# how to turn label horizontal center in material UI in grid?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am trying to make my `label` horizontally `center` in material UI using GRID API.

could you please tell me how I achieve this

https://codesandbox.io/s/007k3v472w

```
 <div className="search-container">
          <Grid container direction="row" spacing={24}>
            <Grid item xs={6} className="abc">
              <label>h</label>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} className="pqr">
              <label>hnnn</label>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
```

https://material-ui.com/api/grid/
I already use `alignItems` but it not work

E**xpected out `h` and `hnnn` should be horizally center of their width.**
currently they are left aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do add container attribute to each of your grid item and apply alignItem to make it center.

Your code should look something like this,

```
<Grid container direction="row" spacing={24}>
  <Grid item xs={6} 
    container
    direction="column"
    justify="center"
    alignItems="center"
    className="abc">
     <label>h</label>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6} 
    container
    direction="column"
    justify="center"
    alignItems="center"
    className="pqr">
     <label>hnnn</label>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Let me know if it help!

Answer (score 0):

Where you have defined your class as abc remove item and replace it with container and add justify="center"

To do it with CSS use text-align: center

Comment: I need to grid API .please remove your answer